# Mongoid override relation setter

Tags: mongoid

I'm trying to implement this pattern

```
class A
    Mongoid::Document

    belongs_to :price

    def price
      self[:price] || calculate_price
    end

    def calculate_price
       #Some logic
    end    
end
```

meaning that a user can either force a price to A or get a calculated price. Trouble is, the setter doesn't work as expected:

```
2.0.0-rc2 :013 > a = A.new
 => #<A _id: 5215b3321d41c89a1f000001, price_id: nil> 
2.0.0-rc2 :015 > a.price = Price.new
 => #<Price _id: 5215b3451d41c89a1f000002, i(inclusive_tax): nil, e(exclusive_tax): nil, tax_id: nil> 
2.0.0-rc2 :016 > a.price
 => "5215b3451d41c89a1f000002"
```

What is the way to override the setter so things work as expected?

I tried to add a

```
def price=(val)
   super(val)
end
```

but there is no `super` for the setter.

Any hint?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question?

Answer (score 0):

What about this work around?

```
class A
    Mongoid::Document

    belongs_to :price

    def price
      Price.find(self[:price]) || calculate_price
    end

    def calculate_price
       #Some logic
    end    
end
```

Comment: In terms of performance, it should be the same as if self[:price] only will work since both will still iterate the _id field off all Price records.

Comment: The problem lies in the self[:price] call which does not work (it does with PostGreSQL though). The point is to know to to access attributes for relations.